# Problem in building and running flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

After some months of stop I'm trying to launch again an old flutter app, but idk I have a lot of problems. I had to install again flutter on the pc.
This is the error:
[image: Part of the errors]

Comment: What version did you originally write your app in?\

Comment: You probably need to migrate your project to a new flutter version or downgrade you current one

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to download the old version of flutter (1.22.4-stable) but i still have the same problem